# Adding conditional statements to an XPath query

Tags: c#, parsing, windows-phone-8, xpath, html-agility-pack

I am able to retrieve data using C# & XPath and display it in a list, but I would like to know how to perform two unique actions.

To start with, my code example looks like this:

```
    protected async override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
        string htmlPagePurchase = "";

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            htmlPagePurchase = await client.GetStringAsync(MyURI);
        }

        HtmlDocument htmlDocumentPurchase = new HtmlDocument();
        htmlDocumentPurchase.LoadHtml(htmlPagePurchase);

        foreach (var div in htmlDocumentPurchase.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[contains(@id, 'odyContent')]"))
        {
            PurchaseDetails newPurchase = new PurchaseDetails();
            newPurchase.Expiry = div.SelectSingleNode(".//ex1").InnerText.Trim();
            Purchase.Add(newPurchase);
        }
        lstPurchase.ItemsSource = Purchase;
    }
```

Firstly, if there is no "ex1" node within the page, can I request a null value be returned or for it to be ignored?  I need to do this as some of the pages I use contain the data I want in an alternative node (I can't control this) and I don't want the app to crash if one of the nodes isn't contained within that page.

Secondly, if the node contains no text within it, can I force an output i.e. within a list of "ex1" nodes, some contain an expired date but one "ex1" node does not include any date as it hasn't expired yet.  When that happens can I return my own value of 'hasn't expired', for example?

This is being compiled in a Windows Phone 8.0 Silverlight App.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should work by checking the node and value, and using your `defaultValue` if no real value is found.

```
var node = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode(".//ex1");
return (node == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty((node.InnerText ?? "").Trim()) ? defaultValue : node.InnerText.Trim());
```

.NET Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/3DAjKH

**UPDATE FOR INTEGRATING WITH PROVIDED CODE SAMPLE**

This should work within your loop.

```
var exNode = div.SelectSingleNode(".//ex1");
if (exNode == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty((exNode.InnerText ?? "").Trim()))
    newPurchase.Expiry = "N/A"; // Default value
else
    newPurchase.Expiry = div.SelectSingleNode(".//ex1").InnerText.Trim();
```

Comment: I'm not sure how to incorporate this into my own code without re-writing the entire thing.  I do not set my own strings, which is what you seem to have done in your example.  However, you have highlighted the end goal I would like to achieve.

Comment: No problem - I added a quick code sample of how you can use in your sample code.